# Weld CDI: Producers in superclasses of alternatives are effective despite cdi-spec

Tags: cdi, weld, jboss-weld, weld-se

Given

```
public class BeanContainer {
   @Produces
   Bean bean = new Bean();
}
```

and its alternative:

```
@Alternative
public class BeanContainerAlt extends BeanContainer {
    @Produces
    int producerInt = 10;
}
```

where Bean is

```
public class Bean {
    boolean didPostConstruct = false;
    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        didPostConstruct = true;
    }
}
```

injected into MainClass:

```
public class MainClass {
    @Inject
    Bean bean;
    @Inject
    Integer producedInt;
}
```

Then:

```
  Weld weld = new Weld()
            .disableDiscovery()
            .addBeanClass(MainClass.class)
            .addBeanClass(BeanContainer.class)
            .addBeanClass(BeanContainerAlt.class)
            .alternatives(BeanContainerAlt.class);
    WeldContainer container = weld.initialize();
    final MainClass mainClass = container.select(MainClass.class).get();
    assertFalse(mainClass.bean.didPostConstruct);
    assertEquals(10, (long)mainClass.producedInt);
    BeanContainer containerObject = container.select(BeanContainer.class).get();
    assertEquals(BeanContainerAlt.class, containerObject.getClass());
```

gives no error. I would have expected that *Bean.class* would have to be added using *addBeanClass* to be able to satisfy the inject in *MainClass*. The explanation is that the Superclass of *BeanContainerAlt* whose Producers should imO not be effective, produces the Bean-Object.
Is that behavior intended or even according to the spec (I did not find it), is it probably defined in the weld-documentation?

The sourcecode can be found in 
[examplesrc](https://github.com/1and1/ioc-unit/tree/master/purecdi-tests/src/test/java/net/oneandone/iocunit/testalt)

```
mvn clean install -Dtest=ReproProducersInSuperclasses
```

in that project should make it run

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the fields and methods annotated with `@Producer` are not inherited - as discussed in the accepted answer to [Why are Producers not inherited in CDI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53234842/1091731)

However, according to the [CDI specification](http://www.cdi-spec.org/specdoc/):

> 5.1.2. Enabled and disabled beans
>
> A bean is said to be enabled if:
>
> - (E1) it is deployed in a bean archive, and
> - (E2) it is not a producer method or field of a disabled bean, and
> - (E3) it is not specialized by any other enabled bean, as defined in Specialization, and either
> - (E4) it is not an alternative, or it is a selected alternative of at least one bean archive or the application.
>
> Otherwise, the bean is said to be disabled.

According to these definitions and code above:

- `BeanContainer` is *not an alternative* (E4) and therefore is *enabled* managed bean
- `BeanContainerAlt` is *a selected alternative* (E4) and therefore is *enabled* managed bean
- `Bean` and `int` are *enabled* because they are *not a producer method or field of a disabled bean* (E2), as `BeanContainer` and `BeanContainerAlt` are both *enabled* (E4)

Therefore producer fields in both `BeanContainer` and `BeanContainerAlt` are used to resolve dependencies.

---

The test fails as shown below when `BeanContainer` is *not deployed* (E1):

```
WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Bean with qualifiers @Default
at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject
net.oneandone.iocunit.testalt.MainClass.bean
```

The test fails as shown below when `BeanContainerAlt` is *not selected* (E4):

```
WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Integer with qualifiers @Default
at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject
net.oneandone.iocunit.testalt.MainClass.producedInt
```

Comment: Any chance of getting a feedback for the answer above?